# Use Regex to select test projects on Azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, glob

I'm trying to skip some tests according to existing of a keyword in its path, the word I want to skip the tests for is GDS (case insensitive)

I use this in **Path to project(s)** in .net core test step in the pipeline:

```
**/*(?!([Gg][Dd][Ss]))([Tt]est.*)/*.csproj
```

But it didn't work, it always freezes in the pipeline as if it waits for an input!

Here are some samples of the project file names:

```
api.tests.csproj //valid
someOthers.tests.csproj //valid

GDS.tests.csproj //not valid (skip)
```

Comment: Try `^(?!.*\b[Gg][Dd][Ss]\.[Tt]ests\b).*\.csproj` See https://regex101.com/r/QuHJMl/1

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns) Azure DevOps tasks not support regular expression.

There is a [fnmatch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) pattern that you can use:

- `*` matches zero or more character.
- `?` matches any single character.
- `[]` matches a set or range of characters.
- `**` recursive wildcard.

You can check the above docs link for examples and also extended syntax.